# Access variables defined in Mako namespace

Tags: python, mako

Normally, "importing" a namespace in Mako appears to only allow access to defs.

```
## base.mako
<%
  somevar = ["one", "two", "three"]
%>

<%def name="foo()">Bar</%def>
```

And an importing template:

```
## child.mako
<%namespace name="base" file="base.mako" />

${base.foo()} # works
${base.somevar} # fails: no soup for you
```

In my use case  `somevar` and `foo` are related.  It would be convenient for me to also be able to access `somevar` from within the importing template.  What is the best practice for doing this?

Comment: Isn't adding a `getSomeVar()` function an option?

Comment: @9000: Normally `somevar` will be an arbitrary python object used as an argument for a function or def rather than just a string output to the template body when rendered.  I'm sorry for being dense:  how do I write/call getSomeVar() in that case?

Comment: You can import function foo, but not a plain name somevar. You could define `def getSomeVar(): return somevar` in base and hopefully use `base.getSomeVar()` as you would `somevar`.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem - the answer is in the documentation on inheritance:

> The attr accessor of the Namespace object allows access to module level variables declared in a template. By accessing self.attr, you can access regular attributes from the inheritance chain as declared in <%! %> sections.

Thus you want `base.attr.somevar` I think.

Comment: This will only work for [module-level blocks](https://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/syntax.html#module-level-blocks) `<%! … %>`, not regular [Python blocks](https://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/syntax.html#python-blocks) `<% … %>`. :(

Answer (score 2):

As user 9000 suggests above, I figured out one way to do it.  I'm posting it so it is documented in case somebody else needs it but I still hope somebody with more expertise can chip in with a better way.

As far as I can tell you can't access functions defined in a module block through the namespace, but you can access a `<%def>`.  By default `<%def>` blocks dump straight to the context buffer so you have to do some contortions:

```
## base.mako
<%!
  somevar = ["one", "two", "three"]
%>

<%def name="getSomeVar()">
  <%
    return somevar
  %>
</%def>
```

Then from another template import the base.mako namespace as `base` and access`${base.getSomeVar()}` to get the value of `somevar`.